# Query performance issues

Tags: performance, ms-access, query-performance

I need help in improving the performance of the following query. It has the purpose to select one record out of a group of records with an identical ID (doublettes). Rules are that Date2 must be the most recent and Date1 must exist:

For each distinct ID in `InputTable (= rst(0) )` do:

```
INSERT INTO FinalTable(ID, FID, KeyValue1, KeyValue2, Date1) 
SELECT InputTable.ID, 
       InputTable.FID, 
       InputTable.KeyValue1, 
       InputTable.KeyValue2, 
       InputTable.Date1
FROM
  ( SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM
      ( SELECT * 
        FROM InputTable 
        WHERE ID='" & rst(0) & "' And Date1<>''
      )
    WHERE Date2 = 
          ( SELECT Max(Date2) 
            FROM InputTable 
            WHERE ID = '" & rst(0) & "' and Date1 <> ''
          )
  );
```

The InputTable has about 400.000 records and ~200.000 distinct IDs and only contains the 5 fields that will be in the Final Table, all of which are TEXT.

InputTable is an importet .txt file and i am working with ACCESS outside of any real database. The Result will be again written into a .txt file.

It takes about 1 second for each ID, which is too long... Is it possible to improve the performance significantly?

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performing those subqueries repeatedly for each distinct ID value is what's killing you. I ran a test of your method on a sample table of 10,000 rows and it took ~2.5 minutes to execute on my notebook. By comparison, the following code consistently returned the same results in less than 0.5 *seconds*:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub UsingAggregateQuery()
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database, t0 As Single
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    cdb.Execute "DELETE FROM FinalTable", dbFailOnError
    t0 = Timer
    cdb.Execute _
            "INSERT INTO FinalTable(ID, FID, KeyValue1, KeyValue2, Date1) " & _
            "SELECT InputTable.ID, " & _
            "       Last(InputTable.FID), " & _
            "       Last(InputTable.KeyValue1), " & _
            "       Last(InputTable.KeyValue2), " & _
            "       Last(InputTable.Date1) " & _
            "FROM " & _
            "    (" & _
            "        SELECT ID, FID, KeyValue1, KeyValue2, Date1 " & _
            "        FROM InputTable " & _
            "        WHERE Date1 <> '' " & _
            "        ORDER BY ID, Date2 " & _
            "    ) " & _
            "GROUP BY ID;", _
            dbFailOnError
    Debug.Print Format(Timer - t0, "0.0") & " seconds"
    Set cdb = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Edit**

I just ran another test on a sample table of 400,000 rows and the code above completed in under 7 seconds